# Painting gas stove top

Tags: painting, stove

I have a gallery series fridgedaire gas stove with several scratches on the stovetop. What kind of paint should I use?

Comment: LMGTFY: appliance paint touch up

Answer (score 2):

I'll suggest "don't bother" - no paint, including "Appliance Touch Up Paint" has the durability of baked on enamel, and yet that got scratched up.

It can be scratched, scratched but (obviously) painted, or scratched but painted but the paint is getting scratched off again.

It will never "look like new" again, and at least scratched doesn't look any worse when the next scratch goes in...

Comment: Advantage of touching it up is that otherwise the scratches areas may start to rust.

Answer (score 1):

I have basically the sentiment that Ecnerwal has, although I will tell you what I do in my rentals or pre-selling.

I hit them with grill-grade/fireplace spraypaint.   I use rustoleum brand and do it in white, black or silver.   It looks good (not like new), it last, and you can redo it in 20 seconds.   Silver and white are very noticeable when chipped and you can go either way with black.

Trying to make it like it did before looks like an eyesore and something that thick will certainly not take the heat and sharp pans hitting it.